# I'm a new android coder. I have the error "Gradle build finished with 242 error(s) and 2 warning(s)"

Tags: android, api, gradle, youtube

I'm trying to write a youtube app in android. I tried to use this example https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples (Java#1). I have only used the import statements from this and when trying to compile I get a lot of errors. I wasn't sure how to import the libraries, first I tried downloading libraries from the internet but that didn't work, although the red error line moved onto further words (for example "import thing.thing2.thing3" before the red error line was under thing then moved to thing2). Then I searched mvnrepository and copy and pasted the code under the 'gradle' tab into my gradle which fixed the red error lines but now I have a lot of errors when trying to run my app (I do not have any red lines in my app as far as I can see). My gradle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "richardcastle324.yahoo.com.elephantyoutube"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
            compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.4.0'
            compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.16.0-rc-sources.jar')
            compile files('libs/google-api-services-youtube-v3-rev176-1.22.0-javadoc.jar')
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
            compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev176-1.22.0'
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-youtube
            compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-youtube', version: 'v3-rev176-1.22.0'
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6
            compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-java6', version: '1.11.0-beta'
            // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty
            compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.11.0-beta'                
}
```

Comment: Post the error messages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what all those dependencies are doing, but I have a basic youtube app that is working with the following build gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jakespeers.youtubeplayer"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files("libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar")
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Just make sure you have the "YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar" file in your libs folder. Find the libs folder by going into the apps names folder, followed by the "app" folder, then finally the "libs" folder. Make sure the file is spelt exactly the same. Also don't forget to change your applicationId. If you need more dependencies you can add them as you need them.

If this still doesn't work, please post the errors you are getting.

Here is the link to download the lib file:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/